# re-attaching jquery function on td after dynamically loading table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to jQuery. I am loading a table through ajax. Inside the table i have one toggle. The on click event attached to it is not working. But if the table allready exist it work fine. Due to the ajax load the onClick function is not attaching to it. The code looks like following

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.mytable .toggle', function () {
    alert("toggle Clicked");
    });
});
```

Html Before ajax

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links" id="tab-links">

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">

    </div>
</div>
```

Html after ajax

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links" id="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>        
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active" >
            <table id="mytable1" class="mytable">
                <tr data-depth="0" class="expand level0">
                    <td>
                    <span class="toggle expand">+</span>
                    Everything Else [<a class="link">99</a>]
                    </td>   
                    <td> 1$</td>    
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Although it seems you are actually delegating.  However your `span` with class `toggle` seems to not contain anything and hence you aren't ever actually going to be able to `click` it as it takes up 0 pixels.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Just put some text in your span.

Comment: hello Rob Schmuecker it have the CSS which show the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<span>` is empty:

```
<span class="toggle expand"></span>
```

change to:

```
<td>
    <span class="toggle expand">Everything Else</span>
    [<a class="link">99</a>]
</td>
```

Comment: as you can see here: http://rotter.net/User_files/forum/53de31853e9b1525.jpg
It does not have any space

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can only attach event handlers to elements that already exist within the DOM when you attempt the attachment.

In your case, the click event needs to be attached once the elements that match the `.mytable .toggle` selector exist in the DOM. Currently, you are attaching them on page load. At that point the elements don't exist, which is why the click handler never gets attached.

Attach the click handler once the table has been inserted into the DOM by the AJAX completion callback.

Comment: The answer is in the question. I was was not using the $(document) in my code. I was using $('.tab'). when i changed it to $(document) it start working fine.

Comment: @Shivay That will work but the click handler will get attached to the entire document. Basically, that means no matter where you click the click handler will fire. If that is what want than great. But if you only want it to fire when specific elements are clicked then you should think about going with my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question. I was was not using the $(document) in my code. I was using $('.tab'). when i changed it to $(document) it start working fine.